# I thought my systemd service (to turn off Bluetooth at boot time) should only run at boot time?

Tags: systemd, bluetooth

I wrote a systemd service to turn off Bluetooth at boot time, but still wanted to be able to turn it on via the Bluetooth top panel applet icon if required.

It turns bluetooth off nicely at boot time and I thought I had tested that turning it on manually worked.

Recently I got some bluetooth speakers and I tried connecting to them.

But every time I turned bluetooth on, it turned off again (after about ten seconds) and the logs show that it was my service doing the turning off.

(What confused me more was that the first day I tried connecting, I managed to connect to the speakers long enough to play a couple of symphonies - it's only since the third day that bluetooth always turns itself off.)

Have I misunderstood? I thought the service would just run once at boot time. Do I have to specify something else?

Below is the latest version of the service.

If I comment out the `Type=oneshot`, it behaves the same. I included the `WantedBy=bluetooth.target` because it creates a symlink from `/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/turn-bluetooth-off.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/turn-bluetooth-off.service` and if the symlink is missing, the service does not run at all.

`sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` does not work any better at turning bluetooth on.

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to always turn bluetooth off at system start time
After=bluetooth.service
After=NetworkManager.service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/turn-bluetooth-off.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
```

and the file `/usr/local/bin/turn-bluetooth-off.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

date > /root/disk_space_report.txt
rfkill block bluetooth
du -sh /home/ >> /root/disk_space_report.txt
```

I run

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl enable turn-bluetooth-off.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/turn-bluetooth-off.service to /etc/systemd/system/turn-bluetooth-off.service.
```

After a reboot `journalctl --unit=bluetooth`
shows (and some of these lines are in red):

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-06-08 17:18:28 CEST, end at Mon 2020-06-08 17:43:45 CEST. --
Jun 08 17:18:41 Otilia systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 08 17:18:41 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Jun 08 17:18:41 Otilia systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 08 17:18:41 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Starting SDP server
Jun 08 17:18:42 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Bluetooth management interface 1.13 initialized
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 08 17:18:44 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 08 17:19:38 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 08 17:19:39 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 08 17:19:39 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

and `journalctl --unit=turn-bluetooth-off` shows:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-06-08 17:18:28 CEST, end at Mon 2020-06-08 17:43:45 CEST. --
Jun 08 17:18:51 Otilia systemd[1]: Starting Service to always turn bluetooth off at system start time...
Jun 08 17:21:21 Otilia systemd[1]: Started Service to always turn bluetooth off at system start time.
```

and `rfkill list all` shows

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

N.B. Sometimes `hci0` is not shown and the soft block is shown against one of the other items.

Now I try turning bluetooth on using the Bluetooth top panel applet. The applet displays ON and then after about ten seconds it displays OFF again.

New output from `journalctl --unit=bluetooth`

```
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Error adding Link Loss service
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Current Time Service could not be registered
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Not enough free handles to register service
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 08 20:43:29 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 08 20:43:31 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 08 20:43:31 Otilia bluetoothd[824]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

New output from `journalctl --unit=turn-bluetooth-off`

```
Jun 08 20:43:30 Otilia systemd[1]: Starting Service to always turn bluetooth off at system start time...
Jun 08 20:43:33 Otilia systemd[1]: Started Service to always turn bluetooth off at system start time.
```

and `rfkill list all` shows

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I can't see what is causing my service to be run again. Help!

Comment: I tried disabling my turn-bluetooth-off service to see what happens "normally". It's not good. On boot up bluetooth is on (if it was on when I shut down the service).

I can turn it off manually (using the Bluetooth top panel applet); I can turn it on again manually but it immediately turns off again; I try to turn it on again and this time it sticks on. This can be repeated indefinitely.

I will make this a separate question, but I would still have a problem that, when enabled, my turn-bluetooth-off service gets called mysteriously every time turning bluetooth on is done.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have found a workaround. I have just realised that the Bluetooth setting (on or off) at shutdown is preserved at the next boot up. So I don't need my service at all. Smiley face.

The vanilla Bluetooth doesn't work too well, but I can live with that.